# R - Change legend label

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I want to change the legend label: instead of the color hex code put "speed", "temp" and "pressure".

```
  ggplot(f1, aes(timestamp)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=speed, color="#e41a1c")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=pressure, color="#377eb8")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=temperature, color="#4daf4a"))
```

[image: Result plot]

Comment: It seems you want to do `+ scale_colour_identity(labels = c("speed", "pressure", "temperature"))`

Comment: Indeed it does the trick too, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
ggplot(f1, aes(timestamp)) +
geom_point(aes(y=speed, color="speed")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=pressure, color="pressure")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=temperature, color="temperature"))
```

to adjust the colours you can do this:

```
ggplot(f1, aes(timestamp)) +
geom_point(aes(y=speed, color="speed")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=pressure, color="pressure")) +
  geom_point(aes(y=temperature, color="temperature"))+
  scale_color_manual("variable", values=c("red", "yellow", "blue")) #or your hex-codes
```